# Meaning of the symbol “$\Delta_\mathrm{sub}H^\circ[\ce{I2,s}]$”

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, notation

One of the back exercises (13(C)) from the book for practice provided at my school asked whether the following relation is true:

> $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ(\ce{I2,g}) = \Delta_\mathrm{sub}H^\circ[\ce{I2,s}]$ at $\pu{25 °C}.$

I know how to solve the question, but the answer would depend on the meaning of  $\Delta_\mathrm{sub}H^\circ[\ce{I2,s}].$ Which of the following reaction does the symbol $\Delta_\mathrm{sub}H^\circ[\ce{I2,s}]$ represent?

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{I2(g) &-> I2(s)}\tag{a}\\
\ce{I2(s) &-> I2(g)}\tag{b}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So Chaitanya Garg's answer is correct. And the answer is (b).

Comment: Sublimation by definition refers to phase transition from solid to gas (no textbook or reference required I would think, but see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_sublimation).

Comment: @BuckThorn I'm more interested in why they used square brackets. Have you ever seen them used like this for the thermodynamic quantities? Or am I looking for the meaning where there is none?

Comment: @andselisk Rather odd to have different types of brackets on both sides of the OPs equation. Typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ ΔH_{sub}(I_2,s)$ can be interpreted as the change in enthalpy when one mole of solid $\ I_2$  converts to gaseous $\ I_2$  at a constant temperature. So the answer should be reaction (b).

Comment: Could you please provide with a reference text that says so.

Comment: @Aseem Mittal, Pg No. 50 Atkins' Physical Chemistry by Peter Atkins and also Pg. No. 165 of NCERT textbook for class 11th.